# constant already defined in php

Tags: php, constants

I have a function that I am trying to run but it shows the message as 
CONSTANT already defined.

I tried to put a condition saying "if defined" about the function but still nothing. Is there any method to ignore this and see the output?

Comment: Could you provide some code? Also, do you have any `include`d files?

Comment: can you show us the code please?

Comment: actually, its connected to several things and in the error message i see "constant..." in 3-4 files (these are like settings file). i am not sure which code i can provide as there are many..

Comment: Makse sure you are using `if( defined('NAME') )` instead of `if( defined(NAME) )`

Comment: which is the function name? have you tried changing it?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Replace this:

```
define('constant', 'value');
```

with this:

```
if (!defined('constant')) define('constant', 'value');
```

Comment: My IDE likes to make this not one line, so I short circuited it `!defined('constant') && define('constant', 'value');`

Comment: This is a little more elegant: `defined('constant') or define('constant', 'value');`

Answer (score 3):

[define()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)

Example:

```
/* Note the use of quotes, this is important.  This example is checking
 * if the string 'TEST' is the name of a constant named TEST */
if (defined('TEST')) {
    echo TEST;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you check for constants:

```
if (defined('TEST')) {
    echo TEST;
}
```

Maybe you're not doing the check properly OR the constant you are checking for isn't the cause of the error, some rogue include file might have a different constant and produces an overlap / re-definition.